# Can I import specific modules from aframe?

Tags: aframe

My website's speed is limited by importing the whole a-frame library which is huge using `import aframe`. I am only using a-frame to view a 360 image embedded on my web page. The components I use are:

```
<a-scene embedded style={aScene}>
  <a-sky src={canvasToFile()} rotation="0 -90 0" />
  <a-camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" />
</a-scene>
```

Is it possible for me to import only the specific components I need i.e. `import { 'a-scene', 'a-sky', 'a-camera' } from aframe`?